# How to avoid "duplicate update of column" exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jpa-2.1

I have quite an unusual case with JPA/Hibernate. I have pushed my example into [GitHub](https://github.com/PawelJagus/demo).

I have a class named `PlayerStatistics` where I use a composite primary key that consists of `matchday` and `player` fields. At the same time there is a reference to another entity named `Match` whose primary key is also a composite one and consists of `matchday` and `homeTeam`.

Now, the `matchday` field is functionally the same field for both of them.
To avoid the duplication of this field in DDL (my schema is generated from the object model) I used `@ForeignKeys` annotation.

```java
@Id
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Player player;

@Id
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Matchday matchday;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "matchday_matchdaynumber", referencedColumnName = "matchday_matchdaynumber"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "hometeam_name", referencedColumnName = "hometeam_name") })
private Match match;
```

It works like a charm and the DDL for it is created like this (no matchday column duplication).

```sql
Hibernate: 

    create table PlayerStatistics (
        enteredTheFieldAtInSeconds integer not null check (enteredTheFieldAtInSeconds>=0),
        leftTheFieldAtInSeconds integer not null check (leftTheFieldAtInSeconds>=0),
        playedFromTheFirstWhistleblow boolean not null,
        matchday_matchdayNumber integer not null,
        player_id bigint not null,
        hometeam_name varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (matchday_matchdayNumber, player_id)
    )
```

When it comes to DML however, specifically an INSERT query, then the Hibernate does not seem to be so clever anymore. The column `matchday_matchdayNumber` is specified twice.

```sql
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        PlayerStatistics
        (enteredTheFieldAtInSeconds, leftTheFieldAtInSeconds, hometeam_name, matchday_matchdaynumber, playedFromTheFirstWhistleblow, matchday_matchdayNumber, player_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This ends of course with an exception (I use an HSQLDB for unit tests).

```
2016-11-22 09:41:10.056  WARN 5892 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -5579, SQLState: 42579
2016-11-22 09:41:10.056 ERROR 5892 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : duplicate update of column: MATCHDAY_MATCHDAYNUMBER
```

I get the same with integration tests with PostgreSQL, so it does not seem to be RDBMS dependent. The problem seems to be in Hibernate.

```
2016-11-22 10:08:42.316  WARN 6696 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42701
2016-11-22 10:08:42.317 ERROR 6696 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "matchday_matchdaynumber" specified more than once
```

My question is. Is there any way to avoid that? How do I "tell" Hibernate that `matchday` in `PlayerStatistics` and `matchday` in `Match` is actually the same attribute?

Usage of a synthetic key is unfortunately out of the question for me.

The error can be reproduced by running the unit test in the class `com.example.DemoApplicationTests`.